# Strongloop add properties during boot

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to add properties to a (previously created) model through a bootscript by using

```
model.getDataSource().definePropery(model_name , property , property_value)
```

While it seems that the model correctly accepts the property (I can see it via  model.definition.properties[property] ) the API-Explorer and propably the full remote API does not update accordingly. Is there a method to force a refresh on those?

My goal is to have a plugin system which extends existing basic models with additional properties and methods, with the methods-part working flawlessly.
I don't want to have to change the JSON file before boot so a dynamic approach would be very much preferred.

**[EDIT]**
I did figure out how to add the method, but it looks so dirty-hacky that I'm afraid it will cause issues. After adding all properties, I overwrite the app's model with the modified model:

```
app.model(model , { dataSource: model.getDataSource() } )
```

Any thoughts on this hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe without your workaround it should be fine, as it seems to be just the API explorer not refreshing. Other functionality should be untouched.

Looking at the loopback-component-explorer code, it [refreshes](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-explorer/blob/v4.1.1/index.js#L115-L121) on the `modelRemoted`  and `remoteMethodDisabled` application events.

So it's not surprising that your workaround refreshes it:

> `app.model(model , { dataSource: model.getDataSource() } )`

Because that causes a `modelRemoted` event being emitted.

Probably a safer way would be to just emit yourself:

```
app.emit('modelRemoted', model.sharedClss);
```

This won't involve all those machinery involved with using `app.model`. I searched on Github for usages of this event, and didn't find anything that would have problems with it. So I believe it should fix your problem for now till loopback fixes this.

In the mean time, I have filed a bug report for this at [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-explorer/issues/206), I suggest keep an eye on it.